Ideas how to make slides easily
I am studying to become a math teacher. I received feedback to make my slides visually more attractive. I'm not skilled in graphical design, but I know the basics of LaTeX, CSS, and HTML. Which is the easier way to make slides: LaTeX + Beamer or HTML5 + CSS + wkhtmltopdf? Or are there some easy WYSIWYG-editors to make slides with math formulas and graphics easily? Python solutions are welcome too.

You're worrying about the format, but first things first: what computer programs do you have at your disposal for showing your slides?

Frame challenge: why are you planning to torture students by showing them math formulas on slides?

There's marp, which is slides written in markdown, supports latex equation rendering and allows you to customize its appearance with CSS.

I too strongly suggest reconsidering making slides for math education. And if you do need to make an occasional slide for an image or a complex computer generated graph it doesn't matter which software you use.

I work in teacher education. Roughly everyone but me uses Powerpoint, and so do all the students. You can add pictures. With some trouble you can also add formulas. You can write them in Latex-code and it mostly gets them. They are not as pretty as they would be with Latex.
If you are aiming more towards high school (in the anglo terminology) than middle school, and in particular more academic and mathematically intense courses there, Latex might be a better deal. I use Beamer, but I also have boring slides, mostly with words or a few formulae on them.

For completeness, I'll note that you can make non-boring slides in LaTeX+Beamer, including fancy formatting, complex layouts, elaborate graphics, animations, and so on. The learning curve is steeper and it takes more work (well, sometimes, depending on what you're trying to do), but the results can be excellent. However, it's easy to make slides overwhelming by packing in too much information, so there's some merit to keeping them simple and (apparently) "boring". Part of the appeal of Beamer is that it does a much better job of helping you keep your slides simple than Powerpoint does.

I might be old-fashioned (I'm 52 years old), but I see a huge drawback in what you do:
I remember sitting in school, watching the teacher writing the formulae on the blackboard, and he was explaining the formula as he was typing it.
Meanwhile I was trying to predict the next character he would write in the formula, something like:
(The teacher wants to write the sum of the first $n$ third degrees of natural numbers)
$$\sum_{}$$
Me: "He will start with $n=0$".
$$\sum_{i=1}$$
Me: (thinking) "WHAT??? Oh, of course: when you want a counter to go up to $n$, your counter can't be the number itself, hence the choice for $i$. In top of that, he starts with $1$. At the end that's the same here, but it's a good idea to start with $0$)"
Me: (Speaking) "Sir? Wouldn't it be better starting your formula at $i=0$? I know it makes no difference here, but in general it's better to go over all natural numbers without leaving the number zero behind."
Teacher: "You're right."
Me: "On top he will write $i=n$."
$$\sum_{i=0}^n$$
Me: "WHATTT??? Oh, of course: he has already defined that the counter is $i$, so writing $n$ on top is shorthand for $i=n$, I see."
Me: "Now just write $i^3$".
$$\sum_{i=0}^n n^3$$
Me: "SIRRR!!!"
Teacher: "Sorry."
$$\sum_{i=0}^n i^3$$
=> By seeing the formula being constructed, I learned a lot about writing formulae myself. So why would you refrain students from such marvellous opportunities?

+1 This! Seeing a formulae being written down sign by sign is a completely different experience from getting the entire formula thrown at you at once. That's one of the various reasons why I find most math talks or (math lectures) that use slides discouraging and hardly useful.

This might be more than you are looking for, but PreTeXt has a reasonably supported revealjs html slides option, which you can make arbitrarily beautiful tikz pictures in.
Obviously the learning curve will be high!  So it might not be your solution, but it might be someone's who reads this post; I've used it fairly successfully.  But if you already really like using things like LaTeX it might be up your alley.


I received feedback to make my slides visually more attractive.

Without context it's hard to see why this would be so important to your mentors.  It's probably easier to have a few goofy math meme slides to build rapport, and then have the less-attractive-but-useful slides.  But it's true that having busy slides is usually counterproductive.
(I would also argue that using slides at all in a math course may not helpful; the course I made slides for was a computer science one, where this seems to be more expected.  That comment is probably too far afield, though.)

I use PowerPoint for the college classes I teach, for the following reasons:
The good things about PowerPoint:

It's WYSIWYG
You can add animations that improve student understanding of math concepts.
You can embed instant-response tools like PollEverywhere
It has "SmartArt" which allows for organized flow-chart type diagrams.
It's fast and easy to rearrange, skip slides, and when presenting, visit an old slide without skipping through all slides (by "zooming out" from presenter view) etc.
Most schools will make sure you have access to it

The bad things about Beamer:

Any time you want pictures on the slides, Beamer is fiddly.
Any time you want to superimpose a picture on top of another picture, Beamer is fiddlier.
You can't embed animations in Beamer

The "Good Enough" things comparing PPT to Beamer:

For the most part, it equation editor is "good enough" -- enable "math autocorrect" and open an equation environment with alt-equals and you can do this mostly with the keyboard (see https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Typing_Mathematics_in_Microsoft_Word for an overview; PowerPoint works very similarly). Meaningful differences from $\LaTeX$ exist, but are easily adapted to over time.
If I really want something that I can produce using only $\LaTeX$, I can save it as an image and put it into PowerPoint.

I recognize this doesn't answer why not HTML/other. But, these are my reasons for preferring PPT for class presentations (when I am not simply doing board work!)

I use LaTeX (with beamer) exclusively to compose slides. As a long time LaTeX user for texts, it meshes well with writing class notes, homework, exams, solutions to the previous. Being able to copy&paste between those is invaluable.

Unparalleled math handling (yes, sometimes you need to include some derivations). Overlays allow to show a derivation step by step.
Can use TikZ to include all sorts of images, by using the overlay features you can even build the picture step by step (for instance, explain how to design an automaton).
There are a bunch of predefined beamer designs, I've never had to design my own (it doesn't look too hard, but I'm lazy and just picked one that looks nice).
Very important to me is that the LaTeX source is plain text, can be handled seamlessly with version control systems like git.
With pdflatex or similar you get a PDF file, software to show that is ubiquous.

